# Is there a good way to manage OnTrigger() functions in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity, this function often has to be attached to multiple objects, must be scripted to the object, and there are only minor changes in the code. Is there a good way to manage this like integrating it all at once?

Or is it best to make a script for OnTrigger() on every object and put it as a component?

I would appreciate it if you could let me know if you have your own good method.

I tried to manage the function separately, but it seems like it must be attached as a component to the object.

Comment: Besides not really understanding what you refer to by `OnTrigger` .. there are many many ways for handling events or observables and listeners or observers .. different patterns, different implementations for each pattern etc ...you would need to be way more specific on your requirements and desired behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually make a component called `CollisionEvents` that contains `UnityEvent` properties for each of the different trigger options. Then when I want to hook into a GameObject's OnTrigger functions, I just include the component and drop the function I want it to call in the inspector.

```html
public class CollisionEvents : MonoBehaviour {

  [field: SerializeField]
  public UnityEvent TriggerEnterEvent { get; private set; }
  
  [field: SerializeField]
  public UnityEvent TriggerStayEvent { get; private set; }
  
  [field: SerializeField]
  public UnityEvent TriggerExitEvent { get; private set; }
  
  public void OnTriggerEnter => TriggerEnterEvent?.Invoke();
  
  public void OnTriggerStay => TriggerEnterEvent?.Invoke();
  
  public void OnTriggerExit => TriggerEnterEvent?.Invoke();
  
}
```

Doing this allows you to access these functions both in the Inspector like normal Unity Events and in code with `collisionEvents.TriggerEnterEvent.addListener()` whilst maintaining a sensible protection level for the property.

I hope this helps answer your question.